# Combine Text Frame Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

Please help, How to combine text frame on two different pages?

Many thanks for the help

Comment: Questions on using general software are not on topic for Stack Overflow. They can be asked on [superuser.se], or, in this particular case, on [graphicdesign.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordinary text linking works over page boundaries.

Just click the bottom right box on the starting text frame and then click somewhere on the page where you want to have the following text frame and it gets created.